# Fingerprint Sensor not getting detected (Asus) (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: asus, fingerprint-reader

I installed my finger print software using the command

```
sudo apt-get install fprintd libpam-fprintd
```

But, when I try to enroll my finger print using

```
fprintd-enroll
```

It throws an error saying
infinity@infinity:~$ fprintd-enroll
Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available

The device I am using is

ASUS VivoBook 15 (2022) Core i3 11th Gen - (8 GB/1 TB HDD/256 GB SSD) X515EA-EJ332WS

Comment: Not all sensors are supported. There is no information about the sensor in your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 supported on Ubuntu or on all linux distos? Also, how can I get the fingerprint sensor info

Comment: Only some sensors are supported by all distros. Vendors don't provide drivers. Some devices are getting support by volunteers using reverse engineering. There is no fixed way how to get hardware information, but most likely `lsusb` will show it.

Comment: The driver for the FP reader is not installed. It is probably not supported. You can check the webpage of the maker or the Asus website. Most of the times it is up to the community to write the driver. If you dual boot with Windows, you can get the information about the FP reader there. Otherwise look for hardware specs on the Asus page, or just let Dr. Google do the job for you. There are a lot of sites that list hardware specs.

Comment: 2022/01/02 3.4 MBytes
ELAN Fingerprint Driver

Description:
The package includes the ELAN Fingerprint Driver, to help the system to scan your fingerprint and authenticate your identity to login or launch application.

SHA-256:
CA2A8C46CEEA95B86684A9F9DA9CCB9312AFD453ED6498791EA638C9B7. Hello, this is the driver required